Is there a method to export the URLs of the open tabs of a Firefox window in Ubuntu 24.04?
Is there a method to export the URLs of the open tabs of a Firefox window, that works on Firefox 132 on Ubuntu 24.04.
This export would be a plain text file that would be able to be imported into a new Firefox window.

This question is similar to: Is there a method to export the URLs of the open tabs of a Firefox window?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
